# Recuperar ID de una funcion a otra laravel

Tags: laravel

Necesito recuperar un campo que está en una función a otra desde un mismo controlador **laravel**

```php
    public function store(Request $request) /* funcion store de Empleados */
    {
        $teamUser = new TeamUser;
        $teamUser->name = $request->id_name;
        $teamUser->id_name = $request->id_name; /* campo al que neceisto llamar en en storeEducation */
        $teamUser->email = $request->email;
        $teamUser->photo = $request->photo;
        $teamUser->skills = $request->skills;
        $teamUser->age = $request->age;
        $teamUser->address = $request->address;
        $teamUser->description = $request->description;
        $teamUser->status = 1;
    }
            
    public function storeEducation (Request $request) /* funcion store de educacion de los empleados */ 
    {
        $teamEducation = New TeamEducation;
        $teamEducation->developer_name = /* este es el campo que necesito recuperar */
        $teamEducation->title = $request->title;
        $teamEducation->country = $request->country;
        $teamEducation->date = $request->date;
        $teamEducation->description = $request->description;
        $teamEducation->save();
            
        return redirect()->route('team-skills.index');     
    }
```

El campo `developer_name` de la segunda función tiene que ser el campo `id_name` de la primera

Tengo dos cruds el primero es para crear los empleados, el segundo será para crear la educación de los mismos, hay un boton de accion que mandará al segundo crud

Comment: Es básicamente imposible lo que estás queriendo intentar por la manera en la que lo explicas, tus dos métodos son dos acciones de controlador que se ejecutan en rutas y contextos distintos. Creo que lo que quieres decir es que necesitas recuperar ese valor luego de un callback a esa otra ruta. ¿verdad?

Comment: ¿Se ejecutan una tras otra? si es asi ¿cual se ejecuta primero?

Answer (score 0):

Lo que quieres hacer no tiene sentido y tampoco es necesario ya que tú le envias el ID, seria necesario si el ID te lo generara la funcion **store**.

Entonces deberias ejecutar en la misma funcion la de **storeEducation** para que realice lo que tu esperas.

```
/* funcion store de Empleados */
    public function store(Request $request) 
    {
        $teamUser = new TeamUser;
        $teamUser->name = $request->id_name;
        $teamUser->id_name = $request->id_name;
        $teamUser->email = $request->email;
        $teamUser->photo = $request->photo;
        $teamUser->skills = $request->skills;
        $teamUser->age = $request->age;
        $teamUser->address = $request->address;
        $teamUser->description = $request->description;
        $teamUser->status = 1;
        $this->storeEducation($teamUser->id_name); //Ejecutas la funcion directamente
        return redirect()->route('team-skills.index'); //rediriges a la vista
    }
/* funcion store de educacion de los empleados */             
    private function storeEducation ($id)
    {
        $teamEducation = New TeamEducation;
        $teamEducation->developer_name = $id;
        $teamEducation->title = $request->title;
        $teamEducation->country = $request->country;
        $teamEducation->date = $request->date;
        $teamEducation->description = $request->description;
        $teamEducation->save();            
    }
```

Pero por otro lado mencionas que haces llamada a la acción a través de un boton, entonces en ese caso deberias de recuperar el ID y ya del lado del cliente vuelves a enviar el ID y lo demas que necesites

```
/* funcion store de Empleados */
    public function store(Request $request) 
    {
        $teamUser = new TeamUser;
        $teamUser->name = $request->id_name;
        $teamUser->id_name = $request->id_name;
        $teamUser->email = $request->email;
        $teamUser->photo = $request->photo;
        $teamUser->skills = $request->skills;
        $teamUser->age = $request->age;
        $teamUser->address = $request->address;
        $teamUser->description = $request->description;
        $teamUser->status = 1;
        $this->storeEducation($teamUser->id_name);
        return [
            'ID' => $request->id_name, //devuelves el dato al cliente
        ];
    }
/* funcion store de educacion de los empleados */             
    public function storeEducation (Request $request)
    {
        $teamEducation = New TeamEducation;
        $teamEducation->developer_name = $request->ID;
        $teamEducation->title = $request->title;
        $teamEducation->country = $request->country;
        $teamEducation->date = $request->date;
        $teamEducation->description = $request->description;
        $teamEducation->save();
        redirect()->route('team-skills.index');         
    }
```